# How can I let Sublime Text 2 automatically edit remote files?

Tags: sublimetext2

I am looking for a feature that the Sublime Text 2 can directly edit a remote file.

It can open via ssh or ftp, and every time saving the file, it can be just uploaded to the remote server.

I want to do so because:

1. I don't like vim
2. I don't want to use a software like FileZilla for every small fixes to my code.

Thanks,

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: @MikeW Thanks for the information. How about the new topic?

Comment: My answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17085084/sublime-text-2-sftp-browsing-remote-in-sidebar/17085873#17085873) might be helpful.

Comment: Here is an event listener:  http://urbangiraffe.com/2011/08/13/remote-editing-with-sublime-text-2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have been using this tool for a few years, https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/SFTP I can highly recommend it.

Oh, it does have a price tag of $20, but it can be installed on all your computers with that one license.

Comment: Does this tool let you view an entire remote directory on the side bar?  The biggest issue I had with Sublime over SFTP using another tool (whose name I've forgotten) only let me edit individual files.

Comment: @masahane You have a few options to do so. They are described here:  http://wbond.net/sublime_packages/sftp/sidebar

Comment: quite useful. I have bought!